# KeyListener method keyPressed not working

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am trying to make a little game using java swing and have gotten pretty far but now my KeyListener is not using the method keyPressed.

Here is some of my code

```
public class Screen extends JPanel implements Runnable{

private static final int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 300, RIGHT = 0, LEFT = 1, UP = 2, DOWN = 3, STILL = 4;
private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;
private int direction = DOWN;

   public Screen() {
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(new Key());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    start();
   }

   public void tick(){
     System.out.println(direction)  
   }

   public void start() {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Game Loop");
    thread.start();
}

   public void run() {
     while (running) {
       tick();
       repaint();
    }
}

   private class Key implements KeyListener{
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            direction = RIGHT;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            direction = LEFT;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            direction = UP;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            direction = DOWN;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
   }
}
```

I am looking at the console and expecting the output to change from 3 (which is DOWN) whatever button I press but it never does. After some time I realized that something was wrong with the keyPressed method, I just don't know what.

Comment: Use the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead - it will solve the problem without a bunch of hacking around.  Also, beware, Swing is NOT thread safe - so modifying he state of the UI from outside the context of the EDT may cause painting issues

Comment: See the example below

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate "Game Loop" thread. *Swing* is event driven. Your key listener code will be called when the user presses a key on the computer keyboard.

As *MadProgrammer* mentioned in his [comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61421299/keylistener-method-keypressed-not-working#comment108654128_61421299)

> modifying he state of the UI from outside the context of the EDT may cause painting issues

In other words, *Swing* is [single threaded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and that thread is referred to as the *Event Dispatch Thread* (EDT) and all your code that changes the GUI should be executed on the EDT only.

The below code is a stand-alone, *Swing* application that displays a focussable `JPanel`. When you press one of the relevant keyboard "direction" keys, i.e. A or D or S or W, the console displays the direction. Pressing any other key causes the direction STILL to be written to the console. Note that I used a [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for the various directions, rather than integer constants.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Screen01 extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    public enum Directions {RIGHT, LEFT, UP, DOWN, STILL};

    private static final int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 300;
    private Directions direction;

    public Screen01() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(new Key());
    }

    public void run() {
        createAndDisplayGui();
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Screen");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class Key implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // Do nothing.
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            switch (key) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                    direction = Directions.RIGHT;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                    direction = Directions.LEFT;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                    direction = Directions.UP;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                    direction = Directions.DOWN;
                    break;
                default:
                    direction = Directions.STILL;
            }
            System.out.println("Direction = " + direction);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Screen01());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. How would I go about changing the code for the Thread ?

Comment: @MatthewTapia what thread are you referring to? If you are referring to the _Game Loop_ thread, then as I wrote in the first sentence of my answer, you don't need it. Do you think that you do need it? If you think you do, then can you explain why you think you must have the _Game Loop_ thread?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), it will solve this, and all other, `KeyListener` related issues without a lot of hacking and head scratching over why it "sometimes" works

Swing is single threaded.  This means you should be careful about updating the state of the UI (directly or indirectly) from outside of the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, this also includes any state the UI might be dependent on.

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

Without more details, one of the simplest solutions would be to use a Swing `Timer` to act as the primary "tick" action.  Each time it "ticks" you'd inspect the state of the input and update the state of the model and trigger a repaint to update the UI

For example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        enum Input {
            UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
        }

        private Set<Input> input = new HashSet<>();

        public TestPane() {
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "Left.pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "Left.released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "Right.pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "Right.released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "Up.pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "Up.released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "Down.pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "Down.released");

            am.put("Left.pressed", new InputAction(Input.LEFT, input, false));
            am.put("Left.released", new InputAction(Input.LEFT, input, true));
            am.put("Right.pressed", new InputAction(Input.RIGHT, input, false));
            am.put("Right.released", new InputAction(Input.RIGHT, input, true));
            am.put("Down.pressed", new InputAction(Input.DOWN, input, false));
            am.put("Down.released", new InputAction(Input.DOWN, input, true));
            am.put("Up.pressed", new InputAction(Input.UP, input, false));
            am.put("Up.released", new InputAction(Input.UP, input, true));

            input.add(Input.UP);
            input.add(Input.DOWN);
            input.add(Input.LEFT);
            input.add(Input.RIGHT);

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Check what's currently been pressed
                    // and update the state accordingly...
                    if (input.contains(Input.UP)) {
                        //..
                    }
                    if (input.contains(Input.DOWN)) {
                        //..
                    }
                    if (input.contains(Input.LEFT)) {
                        //..
                    }
                    if (input.contains(Input.RIGHT)) {
                        //..
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int midX = getWidth() / 2;
            int midY = getHeight() / 2;

            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int spaceWidth = fm.stringWidth("M");
            int spaceHeight = fm.getHeight();

            if (input.contains(Input.UP)) {
                String text = "UP";
                g2d.drawString(text,
                        midX - (fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2,
                        (midY - (spaceHeight * 2) + fm.getAscent()));
            }
            if (input.contains(Input.DOWN)) {
                String text = "DOWN";
                g2d.drawString(text,
                        midX - (fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2,
                        (midY + spaceHeight + fm.getAscent()));
            }
            if (input.contains(Input.LEFT)) {
                String text = "LEFT";
                g2d.drawString(text,
                        (midX - spaceWidth - fm.stringWidth(text)),
                        (midY + (fm.getAscent() / 2)));
            }
            if (input.contains(Input.RIGHT)) {
                String text = "RIGHT";
                g2d.drawString(text,
                        (midX + spaceWidth),
                        (midY + (fm.getAscent() / 2)));
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public class InputAction extends AbstractAction {

            private Input input;
            private Set<Input> inputSet;
            private boolean onRelease;

            public InputAction(Input input, Set<Input> inputSet, boolean onRelease) {
                this.input = input;
                this.inputSet = inputSet;
                this.onRelease = onRelease;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (onRelease) {
                    inputSet.remove(input);
                } else {
                    inputSet.add(input);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

This is a basic example and prints the state of the key inputs directly within the `paintComponent` method.  A more realistic implementation would use the `Timer`'s `ActionListener` to inspect the `input` state and make changes to the desired model accordingly, which is hinted at in the example.

If you require more direct control, then you need to avoid the Swing painting system and take control yourself.  For this, you'd need to use a [`BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html).  This is a more complicated solution, but it is also more powerful, as you gain complete control over when the UI is updated